# OracleDB export to MySQL. DBCatalog Named None

Tags: python, mysql, oracle, migration

I'm attempting to export an OracleDB to MySQL and started attempting using workbench.  I run into the following error:

SystemError: DataError("('22003', '[22003] [Oracle][ODBC]Numeric value out of range. (0) (SQLGetData)')"): error calling Python module function DbGenericRE.reverseEngineer*** ERROR: Reverse engineer selected schemata: DataError("('22003', '[22003] [Oracle][ODBC]Numeric value out of range. (0) (SQLGetData)')"): error calling Python module function DbGenericRE.reverseEngineerFailed

I suspect this might be happening because the DBCatalog is named none which is null in python.

I'm looking for a workaround or  better tool for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MYSQL Bench doesn't support migration from Oracle to MySQL

please go through the last comment on this page

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66609